# Understanding kernel process scheduling

Tags: linux, task-scheduler

I am learning kernel/OS and having a hard time understanding how context switch/scheduling works at lower level.

For example, I have a program simply loops:

```
while (1) {}
```

If I run above code on a single core machine, my current understanding is it will run indefinitely and the CPU basically stuck in the loop forever and become unresponsive, which isn't true in real world.

So how did kernel preempt above process once this program start executing?
Does it require hardware support which allowing kernel thread to kick in every once in a while for context switching and scheduling?